# Who are we and what is our family name?

Tags: riddle

We are siblings: sons and daughters
of a very rich and powerful father.
Different jobs we each perform,
contracted for a year or more.

1. My job is author, of the real and the fictional;
   Many hold me as the eldest, most famous, an original.
   I can write about anything, no matter the tedium;
   As for who I am, I am known by my medium.
2. I am an orator, adept at public presentation;
   I can use many media to convey information.
   I'm the second original, my ego's in good health;
   I even name my product after myself!
3. The last original, my name's a success;
   While not a presenter, I certainly impress.
   I'm a data analyst, and I'm matched by none;
   When it comes to number crunching, I'm #1.

We have many younger siblings: an assistant, an archivist;
But we the originals, are the oldest and brightest.
We've given enough clues, it's time to end the game:
Who are we?, Who's our father?, and What's our family's name?

Comment: As usual with my riddles, please pardon the horrific attempts at a meter; I should have brought a poet.

Comment: It's questionable that Word is the oldest of the Office suite. Word for Windows was pretty much a complete rewrite and a new product, although it retained the name of the older DOS product, and it came out a couple of years _after_ the first Windows version of Excel.

Comment: @OP **You've got too much time on your hands!**

Comment: @CodeAngry, I'm inclined to agree. Also I enjoy making puzzles far too much

Comment: @NeedAName Learn to code. It's like a puzzle with a purpose. Plus you'll have no free time if you enjoy it. win-win

Comment: @CodeAngry So you say; I'm a programmer lol I love programming, but I also enjoy this a lot since I've discovered it. I especially love programming challenges and the like

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are

> The microsoft suite: word, excel, and powerpoint.

Explanation

> Word is an author and used as a document editor for nearly everyone.
>
> Powerpoint is used in presentations. It can convey information in different media types on slides (gif, jpegs).
>
> Excel is a data cruncher, a giant spreadsheet. It doesn't look very nice for presenting but it has powerful number crunching capabilities